# requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'None': No schema supplied while trying to find broken links through Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, request, python-requests

I want to find the broken links on my web page by using Selenium + Python. I tried the above code but it shows me the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'None': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://None?
```

Code trials:

```
for link in links:

    r = requests.head(link.get_attribute('href'))
    print(link.get_attribute('href'), r.status_code)
```

Full code:

```
def test_lsearch(self):
    driver=self.driver
    driver.get("http://www.google.com")
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("selenium")

    driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    el=driver.find_element_by_name("btnK")
    el.click()
    time.sleep(5)

    links=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")
    for link in links:
        r=requests.head(link.get_attribute('href'))
        print(link.get_attribute('href'),r.status_code)
```

Comment: How you get the `links` list? Show your complete code.

Comment: no one will write your code from image to reproduce your problem , add your code as part of question

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
    raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'None': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://None?
```

...implies that the *Support for unicode domain names and paths* failed within the collected **`href`** attribute.

This error is defined in [models.py](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/googleappengine/python/+/db37ba68521201bbe642c1058fd696025f394694/lib/requests/requests/models.py#344) as follows:

```
    # Support for unicode domain names and paths.
    scheme, auth, host, port, path, query, fragment = parse_url(url)
    if not scheme:
        raise MissingSchema("Invalid URL {0!r}: No schema supplied. "
                            "Perhaps you meant http://{0}?".format(url))
```

### Solution

Possibly you are trying to look for the broken links once the search results are available for the keyword **selenium** on [Google Home Page Search Box](https://www.google.com/). To achieve that you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import requests
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://google.co.in/')
  search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
  search.send_keys("selenium")
  search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  links = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='rc']//h3//ancestor::a[1]")))
  print("Number of links : %s" %len(links))
  for link in links:
      r = requests.head(link.get_attribute('href'))
      print(link.get_attribute('href'), r.status_code)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Number of links : 9
  https://www.seleniumhq.org/ 200
  https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ 200
  https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/01_introducing_selenium.jsp 200
  https://www.guru99.com/selenium-tutorial.html 200
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software) 200
  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ 200
  https://www.edureka.co/blog/what-is-selenium/ 200
  https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/ 200
  https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/ 200
  ```

---

### Update

As per your counter question, it would be a bit tough to canonically answer why *xpath* worked but not *tagName* from *Selenium* perspective. Perhaps you may like to dig deeper into these discussions for the same:

- [Bug 1323614 - Cannot authenticate: requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'stage/auth/token/obtain/': No schema supplied.](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1323614)
- [Invalid URL 'None': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://None?](https://github.com/dailybruin/meow/issues/160)

Comment: When I use your code by finding the element by TAG_NAME it shows me the same error but for XPATH it works.
Why is this so?

Comment: @Talib Checkout my answer update and let me know if any questions

Comment: Can you help me in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347439/capture-screenshot-of-failed-test-cases/54347657?noredirect=1#comment95512505_54347657

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I pretty sure there could be better ways to accomplish this and this may or may not solve your problem, In the shore time I'd, I came up this approach and it seems to be working for me

```
import itertools
import requests
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')

# Search 'selenium'
search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[aria-label="Search"]')
search.send_keys('selenium')
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# Resuls div
container = driver.find_element_by_id('rso')
results = container.find_elements_by_css_selector('.bkWMgd')
del results[1]

# links
_links = []
for result in results:
    _links.append([r.get_attribute('href') for r in result.find_elements_by_css_selector('.r>a')])

driver.quit()
links = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(_links))

for link in links:
    r = requests.get(link)
    print(link, r.status_code)
```

**output**

```
https://www.seleniumhq.org/ 200
https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/ 200
https://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/supplement-guide-selenium 200
https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/selenium-benefits 200
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium 200
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software) 200
https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/287842.php 200
https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/Selenium-Consumer/ 200
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ 200
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html 200
```